# Phoenix Channel: By every request, I receive a reply more than the previous

Tags: websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework, channel

I programmed a small app (js) that get all the posts o a blog from the server (phoenix framework+PostgreSQL). The app is working, but at the *n*th call of the API, I get *n* replies instead of *1*:

```
Joined successfully  app.js:18747:10
client getAll call  app.js:18698:8
client getAll reply,  Object { posts: Array[3] }  app.js:18694:10
client getAll call  app.js:18698:8
client getAll reply,  Object { posts: Array[3] }  app.js:18694:10
client getAll reply,  Object { posts: Array[3] }  app.js:18694:10
client getAll call  app.js:18698:8
client getAll reply,  Object { posts: Array[3] }  app.js:18694:10
client getAll reply,  Object { posts: Array[3] }  app.js:18694:10
client getAll reply,  Object { posts: Array[3] }
```

**That is: at the 3rd call I get 3 replied instead of 1.**

Here the files: `user_socket.ex`:

```
defmodule Proto1.UserSocket do
  use Phoenix.Socket, Phoenix.LongPoll
  channel "blog", Proto1.BlogChannel
  transport :websocket, Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket
  transport :longpoll, Phoenix.Transports.LongPoll
  def connect(_params, socket) do
    {:ok, socket}
  end
  def id(_socket), do: nil
end
```

`blog_channel.ex`

```
defmodule Proto1.BlogChannel do
  use Proto1.Web, :channel

  def join("blog", _message, socket) do
    {:ok, socket }
  end

  def handle_in("getAll", params, socket) do
    IO.puts "Proto1.BlogChannel.handle_in \"all\" called"
    posts = Repo.all(Proto1.Post)
    push socket, "getAll", %{posts: for p <- posts do %{title: p.title, body: p.body} end }
    {:noreply, socket}
  end
end
```

And on the client (vue.js 2): The Endpoint:

```
defmodule Proto1.Endpoint do
  use Phoenix.Endpoint, otp_app: :proto1

  socket "/socket", Proto1.UserSocket
```

The socket:

```
import {Socket} from 'phoenix'
let socket = new Socket('/socket', {params: {token: window.userToken}})
socket.connect()
export default socket
```

Some code to manage the channel:

```
import socket from './socket'

class Blog {
  // in the future the construcor will have a single parameter with the
  // id of the blog, now we hava a single blog
  constructor (blogId) {
    this._blogId = blogId
    this._channel = socket.channel('blog')

    this.join()
    this.initOn()
  }
  join () {
    this._channel.join()
      .receive('ok', resp => { console.log('Joined successfully') })
      .receive('error', resp => { console.log('Unable to join') })
  }
  initOn () {
    this._channel.on('all', payload => {
      console.log('payload: ', payload)
    })
  }
  getChannel () {
    return this._channel
  }
}

let BlogFactory = {
  blogs: new Map(),
  getBlog: function (blogId = 'default') {
    if (this.blogs[blogId] === undefined) {
      this.blogs[blogId] = new Blog(blogId)
    }
    return this.blogs[blogId]
  }
}
export default BlogFactory
```

The data fetch:

```
[...]
  methods: {
    fetchData () {
      this.error = this.posts = null
      this.loading = true

      var blog = BlogFactory.getBlog()
      var c = blog.getChannel()
      c.on('getAll', payload => {
        console.log('client getAll reply, ', payload)
        this.loading = false
        this.posts = payload.posts
      })
      console.log('client getAll call')
      c.push('getAll')
    }
  }
[...]
```

**Changed client program after the answer of @Nicd (the following code works!):**

```
<script>
// import BlogFactory from '../blog'
import socket from '../socket'

export default {
  name: 'blog',
  data () {
    return {
      loading: false,
      posts: null,
      error: null
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.channel = socket.channel('blog')
    this.channel.join()
      .receive('ok', resp => { console.log('Joined successfully') })
      .receive('error', resp => { console.log('Unable to join') })
    this.channel.on('getAll', payload => {
      console.log('client getAll reply, ', payload)
      this.loading = false
      this.posts = payload.posts
    })
    this.fetchData()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData () {
      this.error = this.posts = null
      this.loading = true

      console.log('client getAll call')
      this.channel.push('getAll')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that every time you call `fetchData()`, you are adding a new listener with the `c.on('getAll', ...)` call. So for every received message you run an increasing amount of listeners and that is why it looks like you received many messages.

You can check this with your browser's developer tools – at least Chromium based browsers allow you to inspect the WebSocket traffic to see that there is only one received message.